# How I write code to show more transections under one id using php?

Tags: php, html

**I want set page like below**
[I want to set the page like the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd4Ei.jpg)
**But it show like the below picture.**
[But it show like below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROnIl.jpg)
*Now what can I do?*

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root");
    mysql_select_db("simple");
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT c.*, a.* FROM simple_tb c, ac a WHERE c.id=a.sid ");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" media="screen" /></head>
    <h1 align="center"> ABC IDEAL SCHOOL AND COLLEGE</h1>
    <h3 align="center">Baraiyahat, Chittagong, 01772969874 </h3>
<p align="center">Students Tuetion Fee Payment Sheet<br></p>
    <table class="table" align="center"width="800"  bgcolor="skyblue">
        <tr><td width="25%">ID No:</td><td width="25%"><?php echo $row['sid'];?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Name:</td> <td><?php echo $row['n'];?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Class:</td><td><?php echo $row['c'];?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Roll:</td> <td><?php echo $row['r'];?></td></td></tr>
    </table>
<br>
<h4 ALIGN="CENTER">PAYMENT STATUS</H4>
<table align="center"width="800" BORDER="1" bgcolor="LIGHTGREEN">
<tr><td align="center"><B>DATES</B></td><td align="center"><B>DESCRIPTION</B></td><td align="center"><B>MEMO NO</B></td><td align="center"><B>BDT</B></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $row['d'];?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $row['des'];?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $row['m'];?></td> 
        <td align="center"><?php echo $row['t'];?></td>
 <td align="center"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root");
    mysql_select_db("simple");
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM simple_tb");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" media="screen" /></head>
    <h1 align="center"> ABC IDEAL SCHOOL AND COLLEGE</h1>
    <h3 align="center">Baraiyahat, Chittagong, 01772969874 </h3>
    <p align="center">Students Tuetion Fee Payment Sheet<br></p>
    <table class="table" align="center"width="800"  bgcolor="skyblue">
        <tr><td width="25%">ID No:</td><td width="25%"><?php echo $row['id'];?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Name:</td> <td><?php echo $row['n'];?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Class:</td><td><?php echo $row['c'];?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Roll:</td> <td><?php echo $row['r'];?></td></td></tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <h4 ALIGN="CENTER">PAYMENT STATUS</H4>
        <table align="center"width="800" BORDER="1" bgcolor="LIGHTGREEN">
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><B>DATES</B></td>
                <td align="center"><B>DESCRIPTION</B></td>
                <td align="center"><B>MEMO NO</B></td>
                <td align="center"><B>BDT</B></td>
            </tr>
<?php
        $res2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ac WHERE sid=".$row['id']);
        while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($res2))
        {
?>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $row2['d'];?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $row2['des'];?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $row2['m'];?></td> 
                <td align="center"><?php echo $row2['t'];?></td>
                 <td align="center"></td>
            </tr>
<?php
        }
        </table>
    }
?>
```

This will work for you

Comment: Thanks. I will try this.

Comment: If you found any problem with this then let me know.

Comment: **Okey I do same**

Comment: Means this code works same as your previous output?? If possible send me the screenshot.

Comment: How i send screenshot. I do not see option to send picture. Please help me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code now is working fine. You forgot write little sign . I change it like below * <?php
        }
        ?></table><?php
    }
?> *

Comment: Ohhh Yaa got it.  Its a silly mistake.  But after all your problem was solved that's more important. Have a good day ahead.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested loops as follows, this needs a bit of tweaking since it's not tested.

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root");
    mysql_select_db("simple");
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT c.* FROM simple_tb c");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" media="screen" /></head>
    <h1 align="center"> ABC IDEAL SCHOOL AND COLLEGE</h1>
    <h3 align="center">Baraiyahat, Chittagong, 01772969874 </h3>
<p align="center">Students Tuetion Fee Payment Sheet<br></p>
    <table class="table" align="center"width="800"  bgcolor="skyblue">
        <tr><td width="25%">ID No:</td><td width="25%"><?php echo $row['id'];?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Name:</td> <td><?php echo $row['n'];?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Class:</td><td><?php echo $row['c'];?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Roll:</td> <td><?php echo $row['r'];?></td></td></tr>
    </table>
<br>
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root");
    mysql_select_db("simple");
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT  a.* FROM simple_tb c, ac a WHERE c.id=a.sid ");
    while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
?>

<h4 ALIGN="CENTER">PAYMENT STATUS</H4>
<table align="center"width="800" BORDER="1" bgcolor="LIGHTGREEN">
<tr><td align="center"><B>DATES</B></td><td align="center"><B>DESCRIPTION</B></td><td align="center"><B>MEMO NO</B></td><td align="center"><B>BDT</B></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $row2['d'];?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $row2['des'];?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $row2['m'];?></td> 
        <td align="center"><?php echo $row2['t'];?></td>
 <td align="center"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this.

Comment: I don't know the structure of your database tables, I mentioned that it needs some tweaking.

Comment: My first table is *simple_tb* where id, name, etc. 2nd table *ac* where id, sid, etc. Table join id=sid. Now I want to  decorate all sid transection under id.  For example,  first table id 4 only one. On the other hand 2nd table sid 4 not only one, sid has more 4 such 5, 6, or more. Now i want to see on one page all sid 4 under id one id 4. Please look at the previous picture link.